# dbgrid and sql multiple queries in delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm setting up a dbgrid and have a tbutton and tedit field liked to my sql query. I'm receiving result to my dbgrid but is refreshes the result everytime.I would like to know how to adjust my code so that it adds each new query result in the dbgrid as I pass the sql query through my tedit box .

Comment: This is normal behavior of DbContols when they are connected to the same data source. You may connect for example dbedit to table, dbgrid to query. Then dbgrid will be refreshed only when the query is refreshed.

Comment: In your q, "so that it adds each new query result in the dbgrid " is not clear about what you want displayed in the grid.  If the grid is already displaying a set of rows X and the next query returns a set of rows Y, should Y replace X in the grid or should the grid display X + Y?

Comment: Hi Pankaj . It would like to have query result x and y to be displayed in the same dbgrid , building the list of queries as the user click on the tbutton as they go along

Answer (score 0):

Use `TDataset.DisableControls` and `TDataset.EnableControls` respectively

DisableControls tells the dataset to stop sending data-related events to the controls.
EnableControls tells the dataset to resume sending data-related events to the controls.